# recognized a numbers and letters in a inputted string

Tags: java, string, input

so far i have no problem in getting the length but the recognizing the numbers from letters is hard can any one help me here Thanks for the helps heres the new code my new problem is in counting the elements in the string in will not count the numbers inputted like a Address Example 99 San pedro st philippines ..... it will only count San pedro st philippines .........

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise3
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {  
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter String:"); 
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        s = s.replace(" ","");
        System.out.println("Total of Elements is: " + s.length());

        int nDigits =0,nLetters =0,sum =0;
        for(int i =0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
        Character ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
        nDigits++;
        sum += Integer.parseInt(ch.toString());
    }
        else if (Character.isLetter(ch)){
        nLetters++;
    }
   }
        System.out.println("The sum of numbers in the string: " + sum);
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: _if the character is a digit, add the whole string as a number to the rolling sum_...think about it, that's what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with the line `sum += Integer.parseInt(s.toString());`.  You're taking the string value of the entire InputStream, which is almost certainly what you don't want.  I assume you intended to do `sum += Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i).toString());`, which will give you just the value of each individual digit.  Take in mind in the string `hello43world`, it would return 7 (4+3), not 43.

EDIT: To do what you actually want - which is the number of letters in the string, try

```
public static int getSum(String s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            sum ++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This will only count the characters in the string - much easier than trying to not count everything that isn't a character.

Comment: thanks for the knowledge Kevin but in that particular program how do you count the length of the String you input? Example like your hello43world the length will be only 10 it will not count the number

Comment: you can get the length of the string by `s.length()`.  This counts the number of characters, not just letters.

Comment: Err... I think I'm confused on exactly what you want `getSum` to return.  What exactly do you want it to return based on the input string?

Comment: forget the sum i already got it my new problem is when i input like an address like 99 San Pedro St Philippines The output will be              Total of elements is: 21 (does not include whitespace)                    The total number of sum is: 18 like that when getting the total of letter of the input string it will not count the 99 or numbers thats what im trying to get  and thanks a lot for helping me Kevin ^_^